# Riemann Integration Question with unknown range

Tags: riemann-integration

Hi Guys I am trying to understand what is going on as it relates to the range of the X values since from the question, the range is stated in terms of a and b. I have been exposed to a few question where the closed interval is give example([0,1] or [0,4]) but for this question I am not sure how to evaluate this function and determine if it is Riemann Integrable. Can anyone help me.

[image]

Comment: $\int_{0}^2f(x)dx=2b$
We shouldn't concern ourselves with this one point (when $x=1$) in the interval of integration where $f(x)=a$ because that doesn't really change the area under $f(x)$. This should match your intuition of what an integral means. Now can we demonstrate that $f$ is (Riemann) integrable? What criterion was given in the text that your exploring on the topic?

Comment: The criterion which we are looking at is to see if the function is Riemann integrable is the comparison of the Upper and Lower Darboux sum @Mason

Comment: Beautiful. So you have a function which is constant $b$ and then has this one annoying point $(1,a)$ does this mean that your lower and upper darboux sums will converge to different limits as we let the partitions become finer and finer?

Comment: no @Mason, what is confusing me is using the Lower and Upper Darboux sum to show if its indeed riemann integrable based on the unknown range. I do understand what you are saying. Essentially evaluation of both the Lower and Upper sums is where the confusion is.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your meaning with "unknown" range. The range is given: The function evaluates to either $a$ or $b$. You mean we don't know what $a$ and $b$ are? We should just interpret them as some constant right?

Comment: yes @Mason just not to sure how to evaluate the upper and lower sum integrals when it is defined as arbitrary constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's review what these Darboux Sums mean.

$$\begin{align}
L(f, P) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \inf_{t \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]} f(t)(x_{i+1} - x_i), \\
U(f, P) &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \sup_{t \in [x_i, x_{i+1}]} f(t)(x_{i+1} - x_i).
\end{align}$$
Ok. So let's pick a partition  $P$ of $[0,9]$ And compute these sums.

Let $t_0=0, t_1=1/7, t_2=2/7 \dots t_{k}=k/7, t_{63}=9$. 
Then $P=[t_0 \dots t_{63}]$. When we are computing these Darboux Sums we look at the interval

$[5/7, 6/7]$ and we think $f(x)$ on this interval has what infimum value? The answer is $b$. Along $[5/7, 6/7]$ this function has only one value: $b$.

So we should evaluate $$\inf_{t\in [t_5,t_6]}f(t) \times 1/7=b/7$$
To make progress we have to make an assumption about $b-a$ is this value positive or negative or zero? Let's assume $a<b$. Then $L(f,P)=\frac{61}{63}b+\frac{2}{63}a$. There are these two intervals where the $\inf$ of our function evaluates to $a$. Namely and [$[t_6,t_7]=[\frac{6}{7}, 1]$ and $[t_7,t_8]=[1,\frac{8}{7}]$. Note that the $U(f,P)=b$.

So this is how to evaluate this thing on a specific partition.

Comment: thank you for showing me this I really appreciate it. This helped me alot :)